# Proper way to escape ${} in a JS template string

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, template-strings

I am creating a bash command:

```
const k = cp.spawn('bash');

k.stdin.end(`
  alias ssh='ssh "${SSH_ARGS[@]}"'
`);
```

but of course, I have to escape it. I assume the best way to escape it, is using:

```
 `alias ssh='ssh "\${SSH_ARGS[@]}"'`
```

can anyone explain why that works?

Comment: because the specs say so ...

Comment: What exactly is unexpected about this?

Comment: Why even use a template string, if you don't require it,.  just use a single quote instead.

Comment: @Keith the bash command uses both single and double quotes, so one would need to escape those

Comment: @Alexander Are there supposed to be backticks (\`) in your second code block?

Comment: @IronFlare yeah, I just added them for clarity

Comment: @AlexanderMills Okay, in that case I believe my answer does explain what's going on. I wasn't sure without the backticks being there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escaping just the `$` works for the same reasons that ordinary curly braces don't throw errors — an expression within a template string is identified by `${` at the beginning and `}` at the end. If the dollar sign is escaped, it isn't interpreted as part of the `${` keyword, and the curly braces are interpreted as normal characters.

Answer (score 3):

Because the backslash `\` is the escape character as usual, also in template strings. It prefixes the `${` sequence that would otherwise be interpreted as a delimiter.